# Is there any translation of Qur'an into Syriac?

Tags: quran, reference-request, arabic-translation

I am studying the Arabic of Qur'an and it is known that there is a close intelligibility between Arabic and Syriac. For purely linguistic interests, I want to have a Qur'an in Syriac and compare it with the Arabic one by reading them both and I also want to learn Syriac together with the Arabic of Qur'an as well as recite Qur'an in both Arabic and Syriac. Unfortunately, I have never came up with the one in Syriac.

> Does anyone know where to find it? (Web-sites, stores, etc) If you know any links regarding the issue, please, feel free to provide them in the Answers section; even photos of the Qur'an in Syriac are appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Could not find any on the internet. No surprise there because Syriac is almost a dead language, very few people speak it and those who do also know other common languages. So there is little benefit in translating into it.